# Need help debugging Asynchronous AJAX call from a form in a div element to update same div with processed results based on form data

Tags: ajax, html, random, mediawiki

I am using a Mediawiki based website.  The site is http://www.DragonFallRPG.com   The widget in question is the 'Orion's Dice Box' in the left column of the site.

Not sure if that has any bearing on this but here goes.  I have a custom div called 'dice' with a content destination div called 'result'.  Below the 'result' div is a form for selecting a number of dice, and the number of sides for those dice.  There is a processing script, which is tested working to provide a randomized result as if those dice were thrown.  The problem is in the calling of one or more functions, I think.  I found the AJAX method for getting the user input via 'get' somewhere on the web and no longer have any idea where it came from.  I will include the files below.

```
dice_header.php  (include file for <head> portion of webpage)

<style>
<!--[if IE] -- long buttons / button width in IE fix>
<style>.button{width:1;}</style>
<![endif]-->
</style>

<?php $javafile = dirname(__FILE__).'/ajax_engine.js'; ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src= "<?php echo $javafile ?>" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submit_dice() {
    // Get form values
    var no_of_dice = document.getElementById('dice').value;
    var no_of_sides = document.getElementById('sides').value;

    // Construct URL
    <?php $handlerfile = dirname(__FILE__).'/handler.php' ?>
    url = '<?php echo $handlerfile; ?>' + '?no_of_dice=' + escape(no_of_dice) + '&no_of_sides=' + escape(no_of_sides);

var xend = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
var base_url = url.substring(0, xend);
    alert('Handlerfile URL = ' + url + '\r\n\r\n Escape URL = ' + escape(url) + '\r\n\r\n # of dice = ' + no_of_dice + '\r\n # of Sides = ' + no_of_sides);

    alert('url for ajax_get = ' + url);
    ajax_get (url, 'result');
}
</script>
```

The above code is an include in the header of the index.php 
The function call for ajax_get seems to be where it breaks down in the process in the above code.  I don't know if it requires the http portion of the url or not.  I don't know if the escape url is required or not.  I'm hesitant to monkey with the script any further without guidance.

The code that follows is the div block for the widget I'm trying to create

```
dice.php  (include file for my widget / div block)

<div id="result" style="text-align:center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width:100px;
        font-weight:bold; 
        font-size:large;
        border:1px blue solid; 
        margin:0;">

  <?php

  //$filename = dirname(__FILE__).'/ajax_engine.js';
  //$handlerfile = dirname(__FILE__).'/handler.php';

  if (file_exists($handlerfile)) {
      echo "Handler file path OK";
        echo 'alert(\'Handler file path = "' . $handlerfile . '"\');';
        die();
  } else {
      echo "BAD handler file path!";
  }
  ?>
</div>

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin:0; padding:0px;" >
<tr>
<td><select name="dice" id="dice" size="1" style="margin:0px;">
      <?php
        for ($i = 1; ; $i++) {
           if ($i > 20) {
               break;
           }
           if ($i == 1) {
               echo "<option value=$i selected>$i</option>\n";
           } else {
               echo "<option value=$i>$i</option>\n";
           }
        }
      ?>
    </select></td>
<td><select name="sides" id="sides" size="1" style="margin:0px;">
       <option value="4">d4</option>
       <option value="6">d6</option>
       <option value="8">d8</option>
       <option value="10">d10</option>
       <option value="12">d12</option>
       <option value="20" selected>d20</option>
       <option value="100">d100</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td colspan="2"> 
<input type="button" onclick="submit_dice();" value="Roll Dice" style="width:100px;" />
</td></tr>
</table>

<!-- 
Psuedo vs. True Random Numbers
http://www.phpfive.net/pseudo-random_php_functions_and_truly_random_number_generators_article2.htm
-->
```

Next follows the javascript engine I'm using to begin the AJAX functionality... Mediawiki has it's own built in AJAX - but I have no familiarity with it and tried finding a less complicated working version else where that I could tweak - resulting in this headache.
Several alert popup calls made to help with debugging, but I'm lost, and none of these alerts are actually being called... I can't tell why.

```
// JavaScript Document  "javascript_engine.js"
// Get base url
url = document.location.href;
var base_url = "http://";
alert('base_url = ' + base_url);

xend = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
var base_url = url.substring(0, xend);

var ajax_get_error = false;

alert('ajax_engine.js called');

function ajax_do (url) {
// Does URL begin with http?
alert('url.substring(0, 4) = ' + url);
if (url.substring(0, 4) != 'http') {
    url = base_url + url;
}

// Create new JS element
var jsel = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
jsel.type = 'text/javascript';
jsel.src = url;

// Append JS element (therefore executing the 'AJAX' call)
document.body.appendChild (jsel);

return true;
}

function ajax_get (url, el) {
// Has element been passed as object or id-string?
if (typeof(el) == 'string') {
    el = document.getElementById(el);
}

// Valid el?
if (el == null) { return false; }
alert(url.substring(0, 4));
// Does URL begin with http?
if (url.substring(0, 4) != 'http') {
    url = base_url + url;
}

// Create getfile URL
getfile_url = base_url + 'getfile.php?url=' + escape(url) + '&el=' + escape(el.id);

// Do Ajax
ajax_do (getfile_url);

return true;
}
```

Following is getfile.php

```
<?php           //getfile.php  --  used for addressing visual part of code

// Get URL and div
if (!isset($_GET['url'])) { die(); } else { $url = $_GET['url']; }
if (!isset($_GET['el'])) { die(); } else { $el = $_GET['el']; }

// echo 'alert(\'URL in getfile.php = \'); $url';

// Make sure url starts with http

if (substr($url, 0, 4) != 'http') {
    // Set error
    echo 'alert(\'Security error; incorrect URL!\');';
    die();
}

// Try and get contents
$data = @file_get_contents($url);

if ($data === false) {
    // Set error
    echo 'alert(\'Unable to retrieve "' . $url . '"\');';
    die();
}

// Escape data
$data = str_replace("'", "\'", $data);
$data = str_replace('"', "'+String.fromCharCode(34)+'", $data);
$data = str_replace ("\r\n", '\n', $data);
$data = str_replace ("\r", '\n', $data);
$data = str_replace ("\n", '\n', $data);
?>
el = document.getElementById('<?php echo $el; ?>');
el.innerHTML = '<?php echo $data; ?>';
```

Following is the form processor, generating the random numbers result for the AJAX output/update.

```
<?php               // handler.php
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//           Random Dice Value Generator v1.0                  //
//             http://www.dragonfallrpg.com                    //
//             Orion Johnson Copyright 2007                    //
//                                                             //
//     This script is used to create a random number based     //
//             values from the user's input                    //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* double rolldice(int, int)
 * - generates a random value based on the numbers passed as an argument
 * - maximum iterations = 20 (can be changed in the user form)
 * - maximum number of sides per function call = 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, or 100 (can be changed)
 *
 * Usage:  To generate a random total value as if one had thrown that many dice:
 * Note:   Future revisions may include the ability to add additional lines to the user form
 *         to mix types of simulated dice being thrown.
 *
 *   array $no_of_dice(x-1); array value "x" taken from user form
 *   var   $no_of_sides;     value taken from user form
 *   var   $total_value;     sum of values from entire array
 *   echo  $total_value;
 */

// Check variables
if (empty($_GET['no_of_dice'])) {
die ('<span style="color:red;">Number of dice value invalid!</span>');
}

if (empty($_GET['no_of_sides'])) {
die ('<span style="color:red;">Number of sides value invalid!</span>');
}

// seed with microseconds
function make_seed()
{
list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
return (float) $sec + ((float) $usec * 1000003);
}

function rolldice()
{
$total_value   = 0;  /* sum of values from entire array */
srand(make_seed());  /* seed random number generator  // 1,000,003 is a prime number */

/* start loop structure from 0 to $no_of_dice */
for($i = 0; $i < $_GET['no_of_dice']; $i++)
    {
$randnum = rand(1, $_GET['no_of_sides']);
$total_value = $total_value + $randnum;
    }
/* end loop */

/* print/return results to the screen */
// echo 'Total value for dice:  ' + rolldice();
return $total_value;
}

// Taken from http://www.sebflipper.com/?page=code&file=password.php
// for array iteration see also: http://www.php-scripts.com/php_diary/122799.php3

?>
```

If there is a simpler way to perform a div update with a random result based on form input, I'm all ears.  This has been a headache for too long for me.  I'm no code-head, just know enough to tinker and make some things work and understand most things when explained.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read through all the code, but since MediaWiki 1.17.0 there's a feature called [ResourceLoader](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader) (if you have older version you *should* upgrade), which you can use for this purpose.

You can make the whole code into an extension to have it organized in a directory (let's say `extensions/DiceBox`). The `DiceBox.php` file in that folder would then be along these lines:

```
<?php

if( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
    die();
}

$wgExtensionFunctions[] = 'DiceBoxInit';
$wgHooks['SkinTemplateToolboxEnd'][] = 'DiceBoxOnSkinTemplateToolboxEnd';

$wgResourceModules['ext.DiceBox'] = array(
    'localBasePath' => dirname( __FILE__ ),
    'remoteExtPath' => 'DiceBox',
    'scripts' => 'ext.DiceBox.js',
    'dependencies' => 'jquery'
);

function DiceBoxInit() {
    global $wgOut;
    $wgOut->addModules( 'ext.DiceBox' );
}

?>

<?php

function DiceBoxOnSkinTemplateToolboxEnd() {
    $sides = array( 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, 100 );

?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="portlet" id="p-dicebox">
<h5>Orion's Dice Box</h5>
<div class="pBody">
    <div id="dice-result" style="display: none;"></div>

    <form id="dice-form">
        <select name="no_of_dice">
<?php
    for( $i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++ ) {
        echo '<option value="', $i, '">', $i, '</option>';
    }
?>
        </select>
        <select name="no_of_sides">
<?php
    foreach( $sides as $n ) {
        echo '<option value="', $n, '">d', $n, '</option>';
    }
?>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="Roll Dice" id="dice-roll" />
        </form>

<?php

    return true;
}
```

This code outputs the code box HTML in the sidebar and registers the following JavaScript file (`ext.DiceBox.js`) to be available on the page:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( '#dice-roll' ).click( function() {
        $.get( mw.config.get( 'wgExtensionAssetsPath' ) + '/DiceBox/handler.php',
            $( '#dice-form' ).serialize(), function( data )
            {
                $( '#dice-result' ).html( data ).append( '<hr />' ).show();
            } );
    } );
} );
```

This code simply uses jQuery (which is bundled with MediaWiki as of 1.16.0) to send a request to the server when the button is clicked and displays the result in the box.

In the `handler.php` file, there's no place where the random number gets output, so you need to add `echo rolldice();` before the `?>`.

Finally, to make the extensions fully work, add `require_once $IP . '/extensions/DiceBox/DiceBox.php';` to the bottom of `LocalSettings.php`.